# export a texture image from Blender with unpack

Tags: .fbx

I currently have an object in Blender that has a material output which is linked to an image:  [image]

I need to export this as an fbx file to import it into unity.  Following some instructions I did this by first `Unpacking the resources.  When I do that I get the files in a directory named` textures`.  However the images in the example image above do not appear.  How can I get these to also be exported?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this one out?  Post your answer if you did.

My first thought is that if the material "Painting.016" isn't applied to anything, then the texture file would not get written because the data block is "orphaned".